# How to show $ C\le\max\{4(n-1)(||-b||_\infty+||a||_\infty), \sqrt 8 ||a||_\infty\} $

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, inequality

$\Omega$ is a compact subset, $n\ge 2$ is a integer, $a,b \in C^\infty(\Omega)$, C is a positive constant. If
$$
\frac{C^2}{2(n-1)}+(a+b)C\le \frac{a^2}{n-1}
$$
How to show 
$$
C\le\max\{4(n-1)(||-b||_\infty+||a||_\infty), \sqrt 8 ||a||_\infty\}
$$

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Picture below is the origin of this question, I can't get the last inequation.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: When you write $b$ in the desired inequality do you really mean $\Vert b \Vert_\infty$?  Otherwise it's a bit strange that $b$ appears as a function but $a$ appears only in norms.

Comment: @Glitch  I think you are right , I have add the origin of my question and review it . Found there is something wrong,from the pictures,   the (1.12) is right only when $x=x_0$ , so there will be not result like the last inequation. So ,  I think  $-b$ should be altered  $||-b||_\infty$.

Comment: @Glitch  I am very sorry. I read the back matter, and  the theorem 1 must be same with  picture above, so , $-b$ can't replaced by $||-b||_\infty$.  I think there are something I don't understant in proof of theorem 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, for any $a\le b+c$, we have $a\le \max\{2b, 2c\}$. So, for 1.12, we have 
$$
f^2(x_0)\le 2(n-1) \max\{2(-F_u-(n-1)K-\frac{F(u)}{\mu\sup u -u})f(x_0)~,~ \frac{2}{n-1}(\frac{F(u)}{\mu\sup u -u})^2\}
$$
Then, the last equation is easy to get, and $\sqrt 8 $ can be replaced by $2$.